# what is hard coding duplex between devices?

Tags: networking, router, connection, switch

This is the first time I have heard the phrase hard code. As I understand it, hard code means to enter something manually, right?
The video says that you may want to use hard code instead of auto negotiation to specify the full / half duplex between the router and the switch.
Does this phrase mean that we manually specify the type of connection? If not please explain.

Comment: Hard-coding is more of a software developer term as in "they wrote all the defaults in hard code that no one but a developer can touch". Settings that can automatically change themselves but be manually set would normally be "forced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hard coding means telling the OS/Device what speed the connection should be so it does not auto-negotiate.